# Sending TCP packets to specific back-end worker through Linux gateway

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, gateway

I'm looking for a way to implement a gateway that will route TCP packets from clients (1-4 client hosts), to specific back-end worker (docker container), according to some specific identifier (task_id).

Components:
 - 1 Linux server gateway with public IP.
 - All back-end server workers (containers) has only private IP (all
   accessible from gateway only).
 - 1-4 client hosts.
 - clients always use only port 443 of the gateway.

**The whole flow (with 1 client for simplicity):**

1. Clients opens TCP connection to gateway (known public IP) - socket s0 (source port p0) - 
             "management" connection.
2. Client gets new task.
3. Client Sends "new task" message to gateway -using socket s0 (source port p0).
4. Gateway setup a new container, getting its private ip and return to client worker_id - w1.
5. Client opens new TCP connection (new socket+new source port for each worker_id) to gateway - 
     socket s1 (source port p1).
6. All clients packets over socket s1/port p1 should be forwarded to worker w1.
7. Each new task that will arrive to client will trigger again steps 2-6 - creating new backend 
     worker, new TCP connection (using new socket and port).
8. Required behavior:
             - Still All clients packets over socket s1/port p1 should be forwarded only to worker w1.
             - All clients packets over socket s2/port p2 should be forwarded only to worker w2.
             - All clients packets over socket s3/port p3 should be forwarded only to worker w3.
             - and so on…
9. On task finish, worker will kill itself and the relevant mapping in the gateway should be cleared.
10. Additional requirement: In case of disconnection in any of the connections the corresponding 
       connection should also disconnected
       (for example, container crash - w1, which leads to disconnection between gateway to worker w1, should cause to disconnection in the connection between gateway and client socket s1).

I googled and found several directions, but I'm not sure which one will give me the expected behavior with the most simple implementation:

1. Linux iptables - load balancing/routing using linux NAT (DNAT).
2. Unix socat.
3. C code using - select(), epoll() or kqueue().
4. Linux IP Commands.
5. Socket to Socket routing (application layer) - most unwanted (but if this is my only option, do you familiar with open-source
   implementing it?)

Many Thanks!

Comment: This description can't be used to properly implement the task because it is incomplete ( or ambiguous) and uses wrong terminology. If you just copy-pasted task description which you got from other person then you sure need to clarify things before asking SO for advice. It looks like "source ports" are used to reference listening ports at gateway. So you can use docker run to map worker ports to host: **docker run -p $new_port:$container_service_port ... **